# Laravel webpack gives me 0++ in production

Tags: laravel, npm, webpack, production

On a project using Laravel 5.4 and the new Laravel Mix, I have a weird error when pushing live a website.

When I'm in local, and I run the command `npm run dev` everything is working perfectly. dev is the following :

`"dev": "node node_modules/cross-env/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"`

This command execute webpack (which I am not very familiar with) and convert sass, js, coffe, etc... to vanilla CSS and JS.

The problem is happening when live like I said when the command is `npm run production`. production is the following :

`"production": "node node_modules/cross-env/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"`

The traduction is happening correctly but when I go on the website I get the following error :

`Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side expression in postfix operation`

When I dig a little in the js I find this weird thing happening :

`for(var n=t.length;0<n;0++)`

So I have **0++** that would need to be **n++** and when I make  research on the file, I get 115 occurence of the 0++.

I think it is coming from webpack ? a misconfiguration or something ?

Thanks in advance for your help !